# Having multiple layouts in laravel

Tags: html, laravel

In my site I have seven different HTML Layouts. The reason i ended up having so many is because some pages had different headers/footers and some pages did not pass data from the back end which was required for the layout to work. I've ended up with several layouts. This is a pretty big inconvenience. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You can better organize your code. Use blade's yield and sections. If the pages are totally different then you have no choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another big hidden gem of blade I found was the `@stack` and `@push` functions.

You can use `@push` to add sections to a certain stack

In your template

```
@stack('scripts')
```

And then in your views

```
@push('script')
    <!-- Here goes your normal HTML -->
@endpush
```

Comment: Thank you! you saved me a lot of time, in Yii2 , where every controller represented by a view folder with the name of that folder there is a property called $layout; where $layout can be changed, i don't know why there is nothing like this in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

For the layouts that require data, I think you could make it optional in the template and validate the data requirement in the controller instead of the template

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found a better way around to achieve ( **different headers and footers for different pages in laravel** ).

```
views/
├── frontend/
│   ├── index.blade.php
|   |
│   ├── layouts/
|   |   ├── app.blade.php
|   |   |
|   ├── includes/
|   |   ├── nav.blade.php
|   |   |
|   |   ├── headers/
|   |   |     ├── main-header.blade.php
|   |   |     ├── another-header.blade.php
|   |   ├── footers/
|   |   |     ├── main-footer.blade.php
|   |   |     ├── another-footer.blade.php
```

Now in app.blade.php we use the **@Yield('')**

```
 <body id="body">
        @include('includes.partials.read-only')

        @yield('header')
        <div id="app">
            <div class="container">
                @include('includes.partials.messages')
                @yield('content')
            </div><!-- container -->
        </div><!-- #app -->

        @yield('footer')
```

And in index.blade.php i want to add the footer **another-footer.blade.php**

```
@section('footer')
    @include('frontend.includes.footers.another-footer.blade.php')
@endsection
```

In another pages if i want to use another footer then we can just change the **included file** inside the **footer section**.